# Writing an equation with two domains?

Tags: amsmath, mathspec

How do I write the following in LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to typeset it in LaTeX?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL, no, I mean how can I write above equation in Latex? I unable to find the name in google

Comment: Yes, that is what typesetting means. Check this answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551312/218142, which answers a very similar question. Does that help?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is with the `amsmath` package, and then use a `\begin{cases}` environment. The linked answer by LaTeXereXeTaL uses the `cases` package, which in this instance I think `amsmath` is the more advisable package.

Comment: I suggest you open a command window, type `texdoc amsmath` to bring up the user guide of the `amsmath` package, and study the `cases` environment on page 9 of the document.

Comment: The two are essentially identical as far as I can tell.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to write a function (piecewise) with bracket outside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside)

Answer (score 7):

As @Mico and @oliversm pointed out, there are two basic ways to do this.

**Solution 1:** using the `cases` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{f(x)=}
  x, & \( x \geq 0\) \nonumber \\
  0, & \( x < 0 \)   \nonumber
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

**Solution 2:** using the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  x, & x \geq 0 \\
  0, & x < 0
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled output]

Both give the same result, although the use of the `cases` package seems to typeset the result a bit lower on the page than using the `amsmath` `cases` environment. Personally, I like the former because you don't have to remember to go into display mode before. Choose the one you prefer.

Comment: I'd lean more towards `amsmath` over `cases`. Having to wrap it in a math mode is a feature, not a bug, since it allows you to use the same technique whether it's in a plain display math or in a numbered `equation`.

Comment: @DonHosek I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Found it, using cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

   \begin{numcases}{f(x)=}
  x, \: \: \: \: x \geq 0                           \\
  0, \: \: \: \: x < 0             
\end{numcases} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, it said `missing $ inserted`

Comment: Your code does *not* reproduce the screenshot you posted earlier.

Comment: Please give `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} $ f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \geq 0  \\ 0, & x < 0 \end{cases} $ \end{document}` a shot.